# Detect user has scrolled past first section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently switching a header class based on the scrollTop and wrapping the logic in

```
if(scroll_start >= 600) {...}
```

but it doesn't work ideally because obviously the screen resolution changes.

Ideally I would want to do this (in pseudo code)

```
if (first section (with an id) is scrolled past) {...}
```

but I'm not sure how to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: how about using `window.height()` so it will work based off the current screen size?

Answer (score 1):

Get the height of the element, then add it to the position of the element from top

```
var elementPosition = $([element]).position().top + $([element]).height()

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > elementPosition){
        // actions
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```js
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
          var two = document.getElementById("One");
          if (window.scrollY > two.offsetTop + two.offsetHeight){
              console.log("You got it!");
          }

      })
```

```css
 #One{
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
    #Two{
        height:1000px;
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="One">Goto: HERE</div>
      <div id="SCROLL">HERE:</div>
      <div id ="Two"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind but I changed your `alert()` to a `console.log()` so it doesn't spam the alert box when we run and test it.